# Ebay Finding Service API - getting completed listings from known IDs

Tags: ebay-api

I'm using Ebay's Finding Service.

I already have a list of Ebay listing IDs and I know the time that the listings end.

I need to know what price the items sold for. I have tried several things, but I never get the data I need from Ebay.

Using the Ebay Listing ID as the keyword seems to work, but only for listings that haven't expired, example:

https://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=XXX_XXX_XXX&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-GB&keywords=275934844095&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&paginationInput.pageNumber=1&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=20&sortOrder=BestMatch

If I try an item that has completed, I get 0 results returned, eg:

https://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=XXX_XXX_XXX&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-GB&keywords=125660483741&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&paginationInput.pageNumber=1&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=20&sortOrder=BestMatch

I feel like I'm missing something really straightforward (as easy as "&completed=1" in the querystring) - but anything I've tried so far doesn't work